# AccountContactRelation update delay

Tags: rest-api, accountcontactrelation

I am using the REST api to create `Accounts` and `Contacts`, I am also using it to update the `AccountContactRelations` between them (the `Roles` field)

I have a flow where I need to set roles on an `AccountContactRelation`.
I do it this way:

1- Lookup the `Account` relations using

```
GET /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/:accountId/AccountContactRelations/
```

2 - Find the one for my contact

3 - Update its roles list and send it back to Salesforce using

```
PATCH /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/AccountContactRelation/:relationId
```

That works fine, and if I do it twice, 5 minutes apart, I can see the 2 roles are present on the `AccountContactRelation`

BUT, if I do this twice, in a matter of milliseconds, when it looks up the account contact relations the second time, to update with the role of my second contact, the role of the first contact is not present in the roles list.

I am thinking there is a delay between the time I save the relation with a role, and that role being visible when I lookup the relation a second time.

**Question:**

Is that a thing?
If so what kind of delay are we talking about? a few milliseconds? seconds? minutes?

**Followup Question:**

Would it also happen if I were to lookup the relation by its ID the second time using

```
GET /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/AccountContactRelation/:relationId
```

(That would require some changes in my implementation, but feasible)

Comment: I'm skeptical that AccountContactRelation is updated asynchronously

Comment: @cropredy I don't know how `GET /Account/:accountId/AccountContactRelations/` works in the background. As it is not a direct GET on the relation itself, but a listing of all the relations of the account, there might be some indexing going on, I saw that this can cause delays.

Comment: I ended up changing the way I fetch the `AccountContactRelation` to use `/AccountContactRelation/:relationId` instead of `GET /Account/:accountId/AccountContactRelations/` and I don't have the issue anymore.